# Function returns only the first element during iteration

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

this is what I have so far:

```
def sort_contacts(sort_contacts):
    contacts = sorted(sort_contacts.items())

    for (k, v) in contacts:
        return list([(k,)+ v])

from test import testEqual

testEqual(sort_contacts({"Summitt, Pat":("1-865-355-4320","pat@greatcoaches.com"),
"Rudolph, Wilma": ("1-410-5313-584", "wilma@olympians.com")}),
[('Rudolph, Wilma', '1-410-5313-584', 'wilma@olympians.com'),
('Summitt, Pat', '1-865-355-4320', 'pat@greatcoaches.com')])
testEqual(sort_contacts({"Dinesen, Isak": ("1-718-939-2548", "isak@storytellers.com")}),
[('Dinesen, Isak', '1-718-939-2548', 'isak@storytellers.com')])

###############
```

here is the result

```
Test Failed: expected [('Rudolph, Wilma', '1-410-5313-584','wilma@olympians.com'), ('Summitt, Pat', '1-865-355-4320', 'pat@greatcoaches.com')] but got [('Rudolph, Wilma', '1-410-5313-584', 'wilma@olympians.com')]
    Pass
```

How can I fix it so that it grabs more than one key and value in the library of contacts

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: There are myriad sorting tutorials on line, as well as many examples of how to rearrange data collections.  Where *exactly* are you stuck after referring to those?

Comment: You should be using yield or returning the entire list.

Comment: `return [ (k,)+ v for k, v in contacts ]`

Comment: @COLDSPEED thank you I really appreciate the info and the detailed break down all your methods worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the way you return your data. Consider a simple example:

```
In [263]: def foo(data):
     ...:     for k, v in sorted(data.items()):
     ...:         return [(k, ) + v]
     ...:     

In [264]: foo({'a' : ('b', 'c'), 'd' : ('e', 'f')})
Out[264]: [('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

What's happening is that the `return` statement returns the *first* item back to the caller. Once the function returns, it does not resume execution and return any more items as you might expect. Because of this, you only see one item returned.

There are two possibilities as a solution. You could either return everything in a `list`, or use the `yield` syntax.

**Option 1**
`return <list>`

```
In [271]: def foo(data):
     ...:     return[(k,) + v for  k, v in sorted(data.items())]
     ...:         

In [272]: foo({'a' : ('b', 'c'), 'd' : ('e', 'f')})
Out[272]: [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

---

**Option 2**
`yield`

```
In [269]: def foo(data):
     ...:     for k, v in sorted(data.items()):
     ...:         yield (k, ) + v
     ...:     

In [270]: list(foo({'a' : ('b', 'c'), 'd' : ('e', 'f')}))
Out[270]: [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

Note that `list(...)` is needed around the function call because `yield` results in a *generator* being returned, which you must iterate over to get your final list result.

Comment: @COLDSPEED - Which of the 2 is better, yield or return? I ask because I just recently started learning python and I have not seen the yield in the book.

Comment: @O'Neill I think return with a list is good enough. But for large data, `yield` is more efficient.